# R data.table finding min and max within groups

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I have this problem where I have a dataset where a person works in different companies. Now I want to find the duration of each company he worked for. Some person goes back to his previous company to work. Here is my dataset and my implementation, but it doesn't work when he goes back to his previous company later.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), company = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
               year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997))
```

You see person == 1 works in company 1 from 1990 to 1992 and then switched to company 2 from 1993 to 1995. Then he goes back to company 1 from 1996 to 1997.

I thought about using

```
min <- data[data[, .I[year == min(year)], by=.(person, company)]$V1]
setnames(min, "year", "start")

max <- data[data[, .I[year == max(year)], by=.(person, company)]$V1]
setnames(max, "year", "end")

duration <- merge(min, max, all = T)
```

which you get:

```
person company start  end
     1       1  1990 1997
     1       2  1993 1995
```

But what I want is:

```
person company start  end
     1       1  1990 1992
     1       2  1993 1995
     1       1  1996 1997
```

Any idea how to get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rleid` as a grouping variable

```
library(data.table)
data[, .(start =  min(year), end = max(year)),
    .(person, grp = rleid(company), company)][, grp := NULL][]
```

-output

```
   person company start  end
1:      1       1  1990 1992
2:      1       2  1993 1995
3:      1       1  1996 1997
```

---

Or may also use `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
data[, grp := rleid(company)]
collap(data,  ~ person + company + grp, list(fmin, fmax))
   person company fmin.year fmax.year grp
1:      1       1      1990      1992   1
2:      1       1      1996      1997   3
3:      1       2      1993      1995   2
```

Comment: For some reason if the data is larger I need to do it this way:
data[, grp := rleid(company), by=.(person)]    
then    
data[, .(start =  min(year), end = max(year)),
    .(person, grp), company)][grp := NULL]    thanks

Comment: @Gabriel if the data is big, `:=` wil be faster

Comment: Yea it takes me 1 min to finish the operation in 4gb dataset, think it will be faster if we use .I to find the index instead to do it in-memory. Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel can you try with `the updated collapse.  I assume it to be faster

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways to do it, but here it goes:

```
library(data.table)
data = data.table(person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), company = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1),
                   year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997))

data[, c('start', 'end', 'group') := 0]
group_count = 0

for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
  if (i == 1) {
    next
    } else if (data[i, company] != data[i-1, company]) {
    group_count = group_count + 1
    data[i, group := group_count]
    } else {
    data[i, group := group_count]
    }
}

data[, c('start', 'end') := .(min(year), max(year)), by = group]

data = unique(data[, .(person, company, start, end)])

> data
   person company start  end
1:      1       1  1990 1992
2:      1       2  1993 1995
3:      1       1  1996 1997
```

Answer (score 1):

Adopting @akrun's answer

If your dataset is large

```
data[, grp := rleid(company), by=.(person)]

min <- data[data[, .I[year == min(year)], by=.(person, company, grp)]$V1]
setnames(min, "year", "start")

max <- data[data[, .I[year == max(year)], by=.(person, company, grp)]$V1]
setnames(max, "year", "end")

duration <- merge(min, max, all = T)
```